# Setup a mocked class method to execute a Func<Task> parameter using Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am writing unit tests that involves a service method that takes in a `Func<Task>` parameter and executes it under some conditions.

The method looks like this:

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
   public async Task TryExecute(Func<Task> func, string foo)
   {
      // ... do unimportant things relating to string foo

      await func();
   }
}
```

The service calling the TryExecute method looks like this

```
public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
   private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;

   public ServiceB(IServiceA serviceA)
   {
      _serviceA = serviceA;
   }

   public async MethodThatCallsTryExecute(Bar bar)
   {
      // ... do unimportant things relating to bar

      await _serviceA.TryExecute(privateFunction, "baz");
   }
}
```

An example failing unit test including the attempt to set up the mocked outcome when calling `TryExecute` looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public async void TestName()
{
   // Arrange
   var serviceA = new Mock<IServiceA>();

   serviceA.Setup(a => a.TryExecute(It.IsAny<Func<Task>>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
      .Returns(async (Func<Task> func, string foo) => { await func(); });

   var serviceB = new ServiceB(serviceA.Object);

   var bar = new Bar();

   // Act
   await serviceB.MethodThatCallsTryExecute(bar);

   // Assert
   ... failing assertions

}
```

**Problem:** during test execution, the `privateFunction` passed into `TryExecute` is not being executed (i.e. when debugging, I'm unable to step in the `privateFunction` method passed in).

Please let me know if there is anything more I can elaborate on; this is my first question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the signature of `MethodThatCallsTryExecute(Bar bar)` to return a [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `void` (if it is), the rest of code should work as expected, just checked that `privateFunction` is invoked

```cs
public interface IServiceB
{
    Task MethodThatCallsTryExecute(Bar bar);
}

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;

    public ServiceB(IServiceA serviceA)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    public async Task MethodThatCallsTryExecute(Bar bar)
    {
        // ... do unimportant things relating to bar

        Func<Task> privateFunction = () => Task.CompletedTask;
        await _serviceA.TryExecute(privateFunction , "baz");
    }
}
```

The signature of test method (or any other method, which invokes `MethodThatCallsTryExecute`) should be updated to return a `Task`, for example

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task TestName()
{
}
```